# React/Flux store doesn't change it's state

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, flux, reactjs-flux

From 2 weeks ago I'm facing a problem in my React/Flux app. It's done in ES6 and using webpack and babel.

It actually doesn't go inside the _onChange method ones the store emit the change event. So the component itself doesn't render again with the modified state.

Here you can take a look to my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Item from 'components/item/item';
import Actions from './item-list.actions';
import Store from './item-list.store';

const StoreInstance = new Store();

class ItemList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
        this.state = this.getItemListState();
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        StoreInstance.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
        Actions.requestFlats(Actions.setFlats);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        StoreInstance.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
    }

    _onChange() {
        this.setState(this.getItemListState);
    }

    getItemListState() {
        return {
            flats: StoreInstance.getFlats()
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ul className="item__list">{
                this.state.flats.map((flat, index) => {
                    <li className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <Item key={index} flat={flat}></Item>
                    </li>
                })
            }</ul>
        );
    }
}

export default ItemList;
```

My actions:

```
import AppDispatcher from 'services/dispacher/dispacher';
import Constants from './item-list.constants';

let ItemListActions = {
    getFlats: () => {
        AppDispatcher.handleAction({
            type: Constants.GET_FLATS,
            data: {}
        });
    },

    setFlats: (flats) => {
        AppDispatcher.handleAction({
            type: Constants.SET_FLATS,
            data: {
                flats
            }
        });
    },

    requestFlats: (callback) => {
        AppDispatcher.handleAction({
            type: Constants.REQUEST_FLATS,
            data: {
                callback
            }
        });
    }
};

export default ItemListActions;
```

And store:

```
import AppDispatcher from 'services/dispacher/dispacher';
import AppStore from 'services/store/store';

import Api from './item-list.api';
import Constants from './item-list.constants';

class ItemListStore extends AppStore {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.flats = [];
    }

    requestFlats(callback) {
        Api.getFlats(callback);
    }

    getFlats() {
        return this.flats;
    }

    setFlats(flats) {
        this.flats = flats;
    }
}

const ItemListStoreInstance = new ItemListStore();

AppDispatcher.register((payload) => {
    let action = payload.action;

    switch (action.type) {
        case Constants.GET_FLATS:
            ItemListStoreInstance.getFlats(action.data);
            break;
        case Constants.SET_FLATS:
            ItemListStoreInstance.setFlats(action.data.flats);
            break;
        case Constants.REQUEST_FLATS:
            ItemListStoreInstance.requestFlats(action.data.callback);
            break;
        default:
            return true;
    }

    ItemListStoreInstance.emitChange();
});

export default ItemListStore;
```

which extends of AppStore

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';

const CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';

class Store extends EventEmitter {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  emitChange() {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  }

  addChangeListener(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }

  removeChangeListener(callback) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }
}

Store.dispatchToken = null;

export default Store;
```

I have check this code many times and looking at examples over the whole Internet and I got no success.

I's supposed that when I do:

```
StoreInstance.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
```

the store will listen for my change event, but looks like it doesn't.
When I got the new data from the API, I execute setFlats and _onChange is not executed, so no changes on the UI are shown.

Do you see any issue in this code? Anything that could help me to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you need to bind `this` ?! I think it should be `StoreInstance.addChangeListener(this._onChange.bind(this));`

Comment: It's bind on the constructor, so there is no need to bind it after.

Comment: Of course, i missed that!

Comment: But I spotted something else:
`this.setState(this.getItemListState);` should be `this.setState(this.getItemListState());`

Comment: That's true, but I didn't figure it out because it doesn't go inside the this._onChange method, that means the change event is somehow not working

Comment: Hmm, I cannot find any error in your code. What if you add console.log() calls to action creators, dispatcher and store methods? Which is called and which is not?

Comment: Everything is called till it emitChange from the store, but looks like anyone is listening to this trigger change event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually in the store which was returning the ItemListStore instead of an instance of ItemListStore and then in the component I was having another instance, that's why it wasn't communication with each other.

Here is the fixed code for the ItemListStore:

```
import AppDispatcher from 'services/dispacher/dispacher';
import AppStore from 'services/store/store';

import Api from './item-list.api';
import Constants from './item-list.constants';

class ItemListStore extends AppStore {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.flats = [];
    }

    requestFlats(callback) {
        Api.getFlats(callback);
    }

    getFlats() {
        return this.flats;
    }

    setFlats(flats) {
        this.flats = flats;
    }
}

const ItemListStoreInstance = new ItemListStore();

AppDispatcher.register((payload) => {
    let action = payload.action;

    switch (action.type) {
        case Constants.GET_FLATS:
            ItemListStoreInstance.getFlats(action.data);
            break;
        case Constants.SET_FLATS:
            ItemListStoreInstance.setFlats(action.data.flats);
            break;
        case Constants.REQUEST_FLATS:
            ItemListStoreInstance.requestFlats(action.data.callback);
            break;
        default:
            return true;
    }

    ItemListStoreInstance.emitChange();
});

export default ItemListStoreInstance;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any usage of you ItemListStore anywhere. Your component is using the "Store" class, which only extends EventEmitter. The connection to the ItemListStore is nowhere to be found.

This line (In your ItemListStore):

```
ItemListStoreInstance.emitChange();
```

will not trigger the emitChange() method in your Store.

Comment: Actually you made me fix the problem, just thinking in the store class, the real problem is that they are 2 different instances. I will post the solution. :) Thank you very much.